# How to specify/set javascript object options (Ink.UI.Modal Class)

Tags: javascript, class

I am using the [Ink.UI.Modal Class](http://js.ink.sapo.pt/docs/classes/Ink.UI.Modal.html) to fire up a modal with a form. The problem is that I need to empty the container of the modal once the modal is closed (`onDismiss`) and I cannot manage to do it. Currently I am doing it like this:

```
   var modal = new Ink.UI.Modal('selector').onDismiss(function()
    {
       jQuery('.dynamic_container').html('');
    });
```

But it doesn't work (code is not being executed)

I have also tried:

```
modal.onDismiss = (function() {
    jQuery('.dynamic_container').html('');
});
```

but it doesn't work either.

Can anyone help me? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to provide a options-object with the dismiss property:

```
var modal = new Ink.UI.Modal('selector', {
  onDismiss: function () {
   jQuery('.dynamic_container').html('');
  }
});
```

to make it a little bit more readable, this could also be written like this:

```
var yourOpts = {
  onDismiss: function () {
   jQuery('.dynamic_container').html('');
  }
};

var modal = new Ink.UI.Modal('selector', yourOpts);
```